# Excel sum similar items

Tags: excel, sum, formula

[image]

I am new to excel and trying to show 2 cells one with sum of completed and one with sum of pending amounts. How can I do that?

I tried with SUMIF and could not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMIF(B1:B8, "=Pending", A1:A8)` and `=SUMIF(B1:B8, "=Completed", A1:A8)`